# Android 4.4.2 (Samsung s4 mini) - How do I reset the credential storage password

Tags: android, android-layout, certificate

How do I reset the credential storage password on a Android 4.4.2 (Samsung S4 mini)?

I need to install a web certificate (.cer) in my device but it asks me to enter the credential storage password. I have never set this. I have tried setting screen lock (pin and password) but nothing worked and I am blocked because of this.

Anyone's help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The credential storage password is a password to "protect" your saved wifi network passwords. When you log on to a wifi network, the phone saves the "credentials" of the network for later use, and protects them with the password. If you forget the password- or in your case it's simply unknown- enter any password until it threatens you with erasing all your credentials. Keep entering the passwords until it does erase everything (it WILL NOT affect your data). At that point it will ask you to enter a new one, do so and it will allow you to access your wifi. I did the same thing at my University.

source: http://androidforums.com/threads/credential-storage-password.103498/

Comment: Im not sure but it might be the same password?